# blurring text in UIlabel

Tags: swift, uilabel

Can you let me know how do i blur the text in uilabel. Similar to below image.
I just need the first character visible and the rest should be blurred. any approach/suggestion will be helpful.

[image: Sample Image]

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at the Core Image library? There are a few options for blurring an image: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/methods_and_protocols_for_filter_creation/blur_filters

Comment: Thx for the reply Jorge, i will check and get back on this.

Answer (score 0):

[This GitHub repository](https://github.com/organizze/ZzeBlurredLabel) has some code which you can probably use to blur the whole label, but it might be harder to blur everything but the first letter. To do that, you could store the same text excluding the first letter (maybe in a dictionary `Dictionary<String, String>` where the first string is the full text and the second one is the desired blurred text) to blur that. The instructions in the Readme.md file look pretty simple, so if your project uses cocoapods you should be all set. If your project doesn't use cocoapods, you can find out how to install it here: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/95/how-to-add-cocoapods-to-your-project

Comment: Hi Lerminator, i will check and get back on this. Thx